# Are there tools for Metamorphic Testing automation?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, tools

Reading about how to test an ML model, I've found the concept of "Metamorphic  Testing" and this fits perfect on my project. Searching around Google I didn't find any Metamorphic Testing tools to automate some tasks like generate follow-up test cases.

My question is: are there any tools for Automation of Metamorphic Testing available? And how much automation can I achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at the software project here translating texts:

https://github.com/yanboyang713/Metamorphic-Testing-of-Machine-Translation-Software

Comment: Leder could you elaborate on how a graphics testing library will help with metamorphic testing? Thanks!